# Sketching open balls

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, graphing-functions, absolute-value

When working with metric spaces we usually have to sketch absolute value inequalities. I can determine the open balls and everything but the sketching part is difficult, for example for a metric defined as $$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=|x_1+ y_1- x_2- y_2|+|-x_1+ y_1+ x_2- y_2|$$ if I want the ball $$B_2(0,0)
= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: d((x,y),(0,0))<2\}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |x+y|+|-x+y| <2\}$$

I have no idea how to draw these things; although I know what an absolute value function looks like. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us use the following linear change of coordinates

$$\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then

$$B_2(0,0) = \{(x,y) \mid |u| + |v| < 2 \}$$

which should be easy to draw in terms of $u$ and $v$. Then you just have to undo this change of coordinates, which in this case is nothing but a rotation by $-\pi/4$ with scaling, since we can decompose it into these two parts:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}= \sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha& \cos \alpha\end{bmatrix}$$

for $\alpha = -\pi/4$. (In other cases we might have to consider another transformation might not have such an easy description.)

In the $u,v$ coordinate system this is the $l^1$ ball of radius $2$ which is the case $p=1$ in the image below, just scaled by a factor of $2$.

[image]

By rotating it back you get an upright square in the $x,y$ coordinate system. I leave it to you to calculate its size.

Comment: Aren't you negleting that an easy coordinate change isn't always possible and we are working with a metric rather than a norm? But certainly, for the example given in the question, good answer!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortnuately OP did not explicitly mention what kind of metrics are used, and I assumed form the question that they mean these kind of linear changes of coordinates. (Also drawing from the own experience when these kinds of topics are introduced:)